# How to force Flash Player Storage Settings to unlimited?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Can i force the Flash Player Storage Settings to unlimited without use the right click menu?

Comment: Are you trying to do that as a user, or as an app ? if you try to code a way for your app to get unlimited storage without user permission, I'm afraid you won't have any luck about it.

Comment: And there's no valid solution for a user as well. It's just the part of Flash settings that are not configurable from the inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change the settings by modifying the file

*"%appData%/Macromedia/Flash Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/#local/settings.sol"*

and the file

*"%appData%/Macromedia/Flash Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/settings.sol"*,

I just replace the values ​​of these files by file values ​​configured as "unlimited".

Comment: Please, where can I find information on the syntax of that file ?